# Repeating a function every few seconds

Tags: c#, .net, loops

I want to repeat a function from the moment the program opens until it closes every few seconds.
What would be the best way to do this in C#?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Use a timer. There are 3 basic kinds, each suited for different purposes.

- [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx)

Use only in a Windows Form application. This timer is processed as part of the message loop, so the the timer can be frozen under high load.

- [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx)

When you need synchronicity, use this one. This means that the tick event will be run on the thread that started the timer, allowing you to perform GUI operations without much hassle.

- [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx)

This is the most high-powered timer, which fires ticks on a background thread. This lets you perform operations in the background without freezing the GUI or the main thread.

For most cases, I recommend System.Timers.Timer.

Comment: Just an addition - there are actually more than just this - for example, there is `DispatcherTimer` (WPF/Silverlight), as well as other timer like tools.

Comment: Also note that System.Timers.Timer's elapsed event fires on the UI thread if you set the SynchronizingObject otherwise it fires on a ThreadPool thread.

Comment: One thing to note is that if you want reliability none of these work 100% of the time, particularly on systems under heavy load.

Comment: An important note from MSDN:
The Timer class is available in the .NET Framework only. It is not included in the .NET Standard Library and is not available on other platforms, such as .NET Core or the Universal Windows Platform. On these platforms, as well as for portability across all .NET platforms, you should use the System.Threading.Timer class instead.

Comment: @JPelletier Thank you that comment saved me a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 47):

For this the `System.Timers.Timer` works best

```
// Create a timer
myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
// Tell the timer what to do when it elapses
myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(myEvent);
// Set it to go off every five seconds
myTimer.Interval = 5000;
// And start it        
myTimer.Enabled = true;

// Implement a call with the right signature for events going off
private void myEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e) { }
```

See [Timer Class (.NET 4.6 and 4.5)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tcs6ww8) for details

Comment: For the benefit of searchers looking for a quick copy and paste console, I used @IvoTops example and created a sample one here -> https://gist.github.com/HockeyJustin/1161699bd26adb5c054d .

Answer (score 10):

Use a [timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx). Keep in mind that .NET comes with a number of different timers. [This article](https://web.archive.org/web/20150329101415/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx) covers the differences.

Comment: MSDN Magazine link is dead.

Answer (score 4):

There are lot of different Timers in the .NET BCL:

- [System.Timers.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-5.0)
- [System.Threading.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?view=net-5.0)
- [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=net-5.0)
- [System.Web.UI.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.timer?view=net-5.0)
- [System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer?view=net-5.0)

When to use which?

- `System.Timers.Timer`, which fires an event and executes the code in one or more event sinks at regular intervals. The class is intended for use as a server-based or service component in a multithreaded environment; it has no user interface and is not visible at runtime.
- `System.Threading.Timer`, which executes a single callback method on a thread pool thread at regular intervals. The callback method is defined when the timer is instantiated and cannot be changed. Like the System.Timers.Timer class, this class is intended for use as a server-based or service component in a multithreaded environment; it has no user interface and is not visible at runtime.
- `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` (.NET Framework only), a Windows Forms component that fires an event and executes the code in one or more event sinks at regular intervals. The component has no user interface and is designed for use in a single-threaded environment; it executes on the UI thread.
- `System.Web.UI.Timer` (.NET Framework only), an ASP.NET component that performs asynchronous or synchronous web page postbacks at a regular interval.
- `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer`, a timer that's integrated into the Dispatcher queue. This timer is processed with a specified priority at a specified time interval.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?view=net-5.0#remarks)

---

Some of them needs explicit `Start` call to begin ticking (for example `System.Timers`, `System.Windows.Forms`). And an explicit `Stop` to finish ticking.

```cs
using TimersTimer = System.Timers.Timer;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var timer = new TimersTimer(1000);
    timer.Elapsed += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("Beep");
    Thread.Sleep(1000); //1 second delay
    timer.Start();
    Console.ReadLine();
    timer.Stop();

}
```

While on the other hand there are some Timers (like: `System.Threading`) where you don't need explicit `Start` and `Stop` calls. (The provided delegate will run a background thread.) Your timer will tick until you or the runtime dispose it.

So, the following two versions will work in the same way:

```cs
using ThreadingTimer = System.Threading.Timer;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var timer = new ThreadingTimer(_ => Console.WriteLine("Beep"), null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

```cs
using ThreadingTimer = System.Threading.Timer;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StartTimer();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void StartTimer()
{
    var timer = new ThreadingTimer(_ => Console.WriteLine("Beep"), null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
}
```

But if your `timer` disposed then it will stop ticking obviously.

```cs
using ThreadingTimer = System.Threading.Timer; 

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StartTimer();
    GC.Collect(0);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void StartTimer()
{
    var timer = new ThreadingTimer(_ => Console.WriteLine("Beep"), null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
}
```