# How to compare time in c#?

Tags: c#, time, comparison

```
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            if (5 seconds have passed)
            {
                do something;
            }
        }
```

---

How can I check if 5 seconds have passed? If 5 seconds have passed for example, it "does something" , then again if more 5 seconds have passed, it does the same thing again, and so on.

**And important:** If I should use date & time to do it, it should not be a specific time, it should be automatic.

Comment: do u want it do the same thing for each five seconds?

Comment: Checkout this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296897/repeating-a-function-every-few-seconds

Comment: This will be interated 11 times: for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thread.Sleep(5000); But this will block your application. You could use a Timer.

For .NET 4.5 you could use the *await Task.Delay(5000);*

I think FelipeP made a great statement..

But the code you gave, and the description of the problem aren't the same.

The code says, if time is passed.

Your description says the loop must wait until the time is passed.

Update:

```
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer _timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

    void CreateTimer()
    {
        _timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        _timer.Tick += new EventHandler(_timer_Tick);
        _timer.Interval = 5000;
        _timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // do something.
    }
```

Comment: I'm using Windows Forms Application.
I tried:
Thread.Sleep(5000); DOESN'T WORK!
Task.Delay(5000);   DOESN'T WORK!
How can I use the timer? (:

Comment: You can still use Windows.Forms with Task  (Visual studio 2012 needed)

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2012, and this is what I did: do something1; Task.Delay(5000); do something2;


But it didn't delay 5 seconds in between it just did it instantly!

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2012, and this is what I did: do something1; Task.Delay(5000); do something2; But it didn't delay 5 seconds in between it just did it instantly.

Comment: Because the Task.Delay(5000) isn't executed yet, You should put await before it. _await Task.Delay(5000);_  or  _Task.Delay(5000).Wait();_   (nonblocking/blocking) version

Comment: Btw, I'm sorry for inconvenience, I think you're focusing  (:

Comment: Thanks so much it worked, but as I am using a Progress Bar using this method it appears like if the progress bar is jumping steps not continuous (like filling a syringe with green blood).

Comment: Did you use the timer?

Answer (score 1):

You need a reference start date and a "now" date;

```
if(startDate.addSeconds(5) < DateTime.Now)  do something
```

If I understood well the situation could be like:

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now;

for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
{
    //do something that can take a long time
    //...
    //..

    if(startDate.addSeconds(5) < DateTime.Now) //5 seconds have passed
    {
        //do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you kidding? this is nothing.
I just want a delay of 5 seconds can't find but this!!! I don't have to "do something that can take a long time" , I don't have to do something that can take a long time, I want something real not this.

Comment: Not kidding, could you be more precise about the "this is nothing" statement?

Comment: Oh, well, your question was "How can I check if 5 seconds have passed?", that I answered, but now I'm confused, if you need your "do somehing" to run every 5 seconds that is something very different, check the second comment on your question. If none of this options are useful I give up since I'm unable to decipher what you are asking.