# Trigger long running process in MVC without UI blocking

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to have some general guidelines

What I have

- UI Click button --> action

  - Get all foo’s from table using EF
  - Read all related FTP file (for Foo’s)
  - Parse FTP files
  - Update Foo’s (EF bulk update)
  - Return Foo’s to UI

It takes about 2 min to do this

What I want

- No button, trigger this process (every 15 min)
- On completion automatically refresh UI

I’ve learned a lot the last months but I don’t know how to get started on this one.

Some help would be appreciated

Comment: Why don't you create a simple Windows Form Application / Service. You can also use Windows scheduler to execute a task every 15 min.

Answer (score 0):

> No button, trigger this process (every 15 min)

As per clarification, the process needs to be repeatedly run on server, you can use [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) on server side code. There are variations of Timer and each suits different purpose as pointed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296897/repeating-a-function-every-few-seconds).

I happen to find a fantastic article that demonstrate use of timer + SignalR based UI update. Please refer this [link](http://dontcodetired.com/blog/post/Using-Server-Side-Timers-and-SignalR-in-ASPNET-MVC-Applications.aspx).

To trigger the process at client side, you can use a timer and configure it to run in every 15 mins. You can use setInterval and clearInterval API:

```
var timer = setInterval(function(){LoadValues(), 5000});
```

> On completion automatically refresh UI

You got multiple options here:

1. First and probably easiest is, when your timer function fires, send an AJAX request to server and fetch the updated data. Replace the content on UI with updated data. This is basically polling.
2. You can use SignalR to refresh the UI. Its server pushing the update to connected client when the updates are available. More information [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr).

Comment: Thx for the quick response. I actually want the server to trigger the updates, not the client.

Comment: @DannyDeBoiserie - O i see, i got the impression otherwise. I will update my answer.